# canvas drawImage() not always visible

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas, drawimage

20% of the time the image shows up and 80% of the time the canvas is blank (solid red). You can see that the image is available at all times within the render function by looking in the console.

You can replicate this by clicking `Run code snippet` then `Hide Results` a few times.

What am I missing here?

If you uncomment `window.requestAnimationFrame(render);` the image will show up 100% of the time. But obviously I don't want to keep iterating over a static image.

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
      canvas.width = 500;
      canvas.height = 500;

const context = canvas.getContext('2d');

const image = new Image();
      image.onload = window.requestAnimationFrame(render);
      image.src = 'https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/49240/2.jpg';

function render() {
  console.log('render', image);
  context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  context.drawImage(image, 0, 0, image.width, image.height);

  // window.requestAnimationFrame(render);
}
```

```css
canvas {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```

Comment: `image.onload = render`. The `requestAnimationFrame` is not doing what you think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`requestAnimationFrame(render)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) is being invoked immediately, and its return value is *not a function*, it's a handle that can be passed to [`cancelAnimationFrame()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/cancelAnimationFrame). You haven't assigned anything meaningful to `image.onload`.

What you meant to do was invoke `render()` when `image.onload` was called, in which case you should use [`image.addEventListener('load', render);`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
      canvas.width = 500;
      canvas.height = 500;

const context = canvas.getContext('2d');

const image = new Image();
      image.addEventListener('load', render);
      image.src = 'https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/49240/2.jpg';

function render() {
  console.log('render', image);
  context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  context.drawImage(image, 0, 0, image.width, image.height);
}
```

```css
canvas {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```

The reason your code is behaving inconsistently is because you've accidentally created a *race condition*. Since `render()` is being called after a certain delay, usually 1/60 of a second for `requestAnimationFrame()`, its success is dependent on whether that delay is larger or smaller than the network latency for downloading the image or serving it from cache.

Comment: Ah got it, thank you for taking the time to respond and the clear explanation :)